# Unable to start Hive CLI Hadoop(MapR)

Tags: hadoop, hive, mapr

I am trying to access hive CLI. However, it is failing to start with the following AccessControl issue.
Strangly enough, I am able to query hive data from Hue without the AccessControl issue. However, hive CLI is not working.
I am on a MapR cluster.

Any help is much appreciated.

```
[<user_name>@<edge_node> ~]$ hive
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/mapr/hive/hive-2.1/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.4.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/mapr/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.12.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Logging initialized using configuration in file:/opt/mapr/hive/hive-2.1/conf/hive-log4j2.properties Async: true
2017-09-23 23:52:08,988 WARN [main] DataNucleus.General: Plugin (Bundle) "org.datanucleus.api.jdo" is already registered. Ensure you dont have multiple JAR versions of the same plugin in the classpath. The URL "file:/opt/mapr/spark/spark-2.1.0/jars/datanucleus-api-jdo-4.2.4.jar" is already registered, and you are trying to register an identical plugin located at URL "file:/opt/mapr/hive/hive-2.1/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-4.2.1.jar."
2017-09-23 23:52:08,993 WARN [main] DataNucleus.General: Plugin (Bundle) "org.datanucleus" is already registered. Ensure you dont have multiple JAR versions of the same plugin in the classpath. The URL "file:/opt/mapr/spark/spark-2.1.0/jars/datanucleus-core-4.1.6.jar" is already registered, and you are trying to register an identical plugin located at URL "file:/opt/mapr/hive/hive-2.1/lib/datanucleus-core-4.1.6.jar."
2017-09-23 23:52:09,004 WARN [main] DataNucleus.General: Plugin (Bundle) "org.datanucleus.store.rdbms" is already registered. Ensure you dont have multiple JAR versions of the same plugin in the classpath. The URL "file:/opt/mapr/spark/spark-2.1.0/jars/datanucleus-rdbms-4.1.19.jar" is already registered, and you are trying to register an identical plugin located at URL "file:/opt/mapr/hive/hive-2.1/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-4.1.7.jar."
2017-09-23 23:52:09,038 INFO [main] DataNucleus.Persistence: Property datanucleus.cache.level2 unknown - will be ignored
2017-09-23 23:52:09,039 INFO [main] DataNucleus.Persistence: Property hive.metastore.integral.jdo.pushdown unknown - will be ignored
2017-09-23 23:52:14,2251 ERROR JniCommon fs/client/fileclient/cc/jni_MapRClient.cc:2172 Thread: 20235 mkdirs failed for /user/<user_name>, error 13
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: User <user_name>(user id 50005586) has been denied access to create <user_name>
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:617)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.beginStart(SessionState.java:531)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:714)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:646)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:641)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: User <user_name>(user id 50005586) has been denied access to create <user_name>
at com.mapr.fs.MapRFileSystem.makeDir(MapRFileSystem.java:1256)
at com.mapr.fs.MapRFileSystem.mkdirs(MapRFileSystem.java:1276)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.mkdirs(FileSystem.java:1913)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.DagUtils.getDefaultDestDir(DagUtils.java:823)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.DagUtils.getHiveJarDirectory(DagUtils.java:917)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezSessionState.createJarLocalResource(TezSessionState.java:616)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezSessionState.openInternal(TezSessionState.java:256)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezSessionState.beginOpen(TezSessionState.java:220)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:614)
... 10 more
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is saying you're defined access to create a directory in the file system. This is likely `/user/<user name>`, which will need to be added by the HDFS / MapR FS super user.

> I am able to query hive data from Hue without the AccessControl

Hue communicates via Thrift and HiveServer2.

Hive CLI bypasses HiveServer2 and is deprecated.

You should use Beeline instead.

```
beeline -n $(whoami) -u jdbc:hive2://hiveserver:10000/default
```

And if you're in a kerberized cluster, then you'll need some extra options there.